# Can one hash value in a query have different execution plans in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Can one hash value in a query have different execution plans in oracle.

As I'm confused how oracle generates the hash value of particular query.

Could you please explain in details with some example. As I'm relatively new in this concept.

Comment: See maybe http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2009/02/22/sql_id-is-just-a-fancy-representation-of-hash-value/comment-page-2/#comment-172432

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: this is my understanding.  Later on today I will post a working proof (but not right now)

---

Plans are associated with child cursors, which are the running instances of a statement.

Consider the situation it which session A fires off a long-running query, by executing a stored procedure.

If session B gathers fresh statistics on a table in that query then executes the stored proc the optimizer will re-evaluate the query and the fresh stats may cause it to choose a different plan.  So the HASH_VALUE of the parent query will have multiple PLAN_HASH_VALUE in [the V$SQL_PLAN view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2120.htm#REFRN30250).